# "Its harder than you make it look (like)."

Tags: grammar

Adding like to the above sentence is wrong isnt it? I am not entirely surely so I have to ask.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, "like" is unnecessary here.

It's because the word "hard" is an adjective, and when you want to use only an adjective to express that something looks or looks like something, the sentence has to take the form of "subject + ***look(s)*** + adjective".  You cannot say "subject + ***look(s) like*** +  adjective.".

What comes after "*look(s) like*" is most likely a noun, or an adjective accompanied by a noun, or a complete sentence.

Here are some examples.

**<"look" + adjective>**

- She *looks tired*.
- You *look hungry*.
- He *looks American*.
- This *looks easy*.

**<"look like" + an adjective accompanied by a noun, or a complete sentence>**

- He *looks like a nice person*.
- She *looks like she is tired*.
- You *look like you are hungry*.
- He *looks like he is American*.
- You *look like you didn’t sleep*.
- They *look like they are having fun*.

And what is used in your example sentence is a comparative adjective, so the sentence must take the form of "subject + look(s) + adjective", so the "like" is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot end a sentence with a preposition, that is why your sentence is not correct.

> Is it ok to end a sentence with a preposition?
>
> You should **NOT** end a sentence with a preposition
>   when the sentence would mean the same thing if you
>   left off the preposition.

- Where are you at? (WRONG) because “Where are you?” means
  the same thing.

> There are many sentences where the final
>   preposition is part of a **phrasal verb**, so it is OK.

- Susie is going to throw up!
- Where did you grow up?

*Page 10*, http://www.american.edu/ocl/asac/upload/Grammar-Workshop-Word-choice-and-Common-Grammar-Mistakes.pdf